# How to enumerate rows in pandas with nonunique values in groups

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation

I am working with expeditions geodata. Could you help with enumeration of stations and records for the same station depending on expedition ID (ID), date (Date), latitude (Lat), longitude (Lon) and some value (Val, it is not reasonable for enumeration)? Assume that station is a group of rows with the same (ID,Date,Lat,Lon), expedition is a group of rows with the same ID.
Dataframe is sorted by 4 columns as in example.

[Dataset and required columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1BYX.png)

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,'2017/10/10',70.1,30.4,10],\
    [1,'2017/10/10',70.1,31.4,20],\
    [1,'2017/10/10',70.1,31.4,10],\
    [1,'2017/10/10',70.1,31.4,10],\
    [1,'2017/10/12',70.1,31.4,20],\
    [2,'2017/12/10',70.1,30.4,20],\
    [2,'2017/12/10',70.1,31.4,20]];

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['ID','Date','Lat','Lon','Val']);
```

Additional (I need it, St for station number and Rec for record number within the same station data; output for example above):

```
df['St'] = [1,2,2,2,3,1,2];
df['Rec'] = [1,1,2,3,1,1,1];
print(df)
```

I tried and used groupby/cumcount/agg/factorize but have not solved my problem.

Any help! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for. Could you provide an example dataframe of your desired result.

Comment: Example created with written code is attached (picture by link). St and Rec columns are desired output

Comment: I'm still not 100% clear on the logic used to decide these values. However, you could use `unique()` on a column to get a list of the unique values, and then `for i in len(unique())` or `enumerate(unique())` to create a corresponding list of ascending numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create `'St'`, you can use `groupby` on `'ID'` and then check when `any` of the columns `'Date','Lat','Lon'` is different than the previous one using `shift`, and use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to get the numbers you want, such as:

```
df['St'] = (df.groupby(['ID'])
              .apply(lambda x: (x[['Date','Lat','Lon']].shift() != x[['Date','Lat','Lon']])
                               .any(axis=1).cumsum())).values
```

And to create `'Rec'`, you also need `groupby` but on all columns `'ID','Date','Lat','Lon'` and then use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and `add` such as:

```
df['Rec'] = df.groupby(['ID','Date','Lat','Lon']).cumcount().add(1)
```

and you get:

```
   ID        Date   Lat   Lon  Val  St  Rec
0   1  2017/10/10  70.1  30.4   10   1    1
1   1  2017/10/10  70.1  31.4   20   2    1
2   1  2017/10/10  70.1  31.4   10   2    2
3   1  2017/10/10  70.1  31.4   10   2    3
4   1  2017/10/12  70.1  31.4   20   3    1
5   2  2017/12/10  70.1  30.4   20   1    1
6   2  2017/12/10  70.1  31.4   20   2    1
```